# kubernetes pod unable to connect to external database

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, dotnetcorecli

I have an external postgres database (using digital ocean); I am able to connect to it from my laptop but I get a connection timeout from my minikube kubernetes pod.
This is in dotnet core (not sure if that matters)

fail: Program[0]
identity-55595689b5-qb8gh identity       Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to :25060

I also added external IP and external name service .. but still getting timeouts.. could anyone please let me know what I might be doing wrong

Comment: are you white listing local IP in postgres to connect ?

Answer (score 0):

The below information derived from [santiesuite  Help portal](https://help.santesuite.org/knowledgebase/sdb-kb/kb008-postgresql-connections-fail-with-block-message)

> **Cause**: The cause lies with an overflow of connections against the PostgreSQL server. This is very common when hosting the IMS on AWS or
> other hosted providers which limit the number of concurrent
> connections to the server.
>
> **Below workarounds can help**:
>
> 1)increasing the maximum connections settings in postgres.config
>
> 2)force-disconnect all clients on your database by running the
> following command
>
> ```
> select pg_terminate_backend(pid)
> from pg_stat_activity
> where datname = 'yourdatabasename
> ```
>
> '
>
> 3)disable multi-threaded fetches from the data store with the
> following setting on your  element
>
> ```
>  <openiz.persistence.data.ado>
>          <connectionManager stm="true" 
>               maxRequests="4"
>               />
> ```
>
> 4)reduce the number of IMS instances contacting the particular
> database server
>
> 5)scale-out the database to introduce read-only nodes,reducing the
> load on the primary data server.

Comment: I am using .net core (entity framework) let me see how the maxRequests can be enabled there; also the strange thing is .. the connection timesout  and if I wait for 10 mins ... it starts working again; I am wondering if I should just host the database inside of kubernetes itself (since  I am worried going live with not knowing the reason); many thanks for your suggestion (will try)

Comment: Actually I ended up spinning up my postgres inside my cluster for now; also for the external db; I created a "external" service -- it did work (but not sure if the timeout problem got solved because of it)

Comment: Many thanks for this -- I will try to get us a specific use case for us to debug; will let you know in some days